# Преобразование newtonsoft.json.Linq.JToken в List<string>

Tags: c#, json

Не до конца понимаю, почему появляется ошибка.

```
    location _location = JsonUtility.FromJson<location>(mytxtData.text);
    List<string> result = (List<string>)jobject["locations"][args[0]][args[1]][args[2]][args[3]][args[4]]["requirements"]["equal"];
```

Ошибка:

```
не удается преобразовать `newtonsoft.json.Linq.JToken` в `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`
```

```
"locations": {
    "city": {
      "tavern": {
        "sublocation": {
          "room1": {
            "withTheMan": {
              "requirements": {
                "equal": [
                  "achievement1",
                  "achievement2"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

````
public class Less
{
    public string name;
    public float number;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class More
{
    public string name;
    public float number;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Requirements
{
    public List<string> equal;
    public List<string> nonEqual;
    public More[] more;
    public Less[] less;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class requirementsInfo
{
    public Requirements requirements;
    public List<string> possibleActions;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Room1
{
    public requirementsInfo withTheMan;
    public requirementsInfo withoutTheMan;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class TavernSublocation
{
    public Room1 room1;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class TavernLocation
{
    public TavernSublocation sublocation;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class City
{
    public TavernLocation tavern;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class locationInfo
{
    public City city;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class location
{
    public locationInfo locations;
}```
````

Comment: Json и класс `location` выложите. А то мы по кофейной гуще гадать должны?

Comment: поправил вопрос

Comment: Во первых, раз это Unity, то и метка должна стоять соответствующая, верно? Во вторых, вы какой то бред делаете как по мне. 1. Если там используется `newtonsoft.json`, то писать везде `[System.Serializable]` бессмысленно (хз, может фича юнити какая...). 2. Зачем вы загружаете JSON 2 раза? Первый, как структуру классов - `JsonUtility.FromJson<location>(mytxtData.text)`, а второй, как JObject - `(List<string>)jobject["locations"]`. У вас же первая десериализация должна была пройти как надо и в вашей `_location` должны быть все необходимые данные. Работайте с ними (`_location.locations.city...`).

Comment: 3. Почему такие ужасные имена? В C# принято писать по определенному стилю, который называется [CamelCase](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). Тогда у вас уже будет к примеру не `public requirements_info with_the_man;`, а `public RequirementsInfo WithMan;`, а что бы JSON смог понять, что это свойство имеет другое название, добавляете атрибут `[JsonProperty("with_the_man")]`. Ну и 4. Если все же захотите использовать JObject (что очень сильно не советую), откажитесь от этой ужасной портянки - `[args[0]][args[1]][args[2]][args[3]][args[4]]`, вынесите в отдельные свойства.

Comment: Ну и напоследок, именно из за этой ужасной портянки неизвестных нам значений, я не думаю, что кто то сможет вам помочь. Вы уверены, что получаете нужные данные путем выполнения этого `jobject["locations"][args[0]][args[1]][args[2]][args[3]][args[4]]["requirements"]["equal"]`? Вы уверены, что там сейчас коллекция? Судя по ошибке, нет, ибо у `newtonsoft.json` коллекция, это JArray, а JToken если я не ошибаюсь, это обычный объект. Выполните постепенно все эти запросы и посмотрите что каждый вам возвращает и где конкретно вы ошиблись.

Comment: Что касается того, что я дважды загружаю JSON - это остаток предыдущей пропытки. Да, я в первую очередь проверил, что в args передаются верные данные. Скажу больше, если делать вот так: `List<string> myList = _locations.location.city.sublocation.room_1.with_the_man.requirements.equal` Все работает правильно